# Send data pushed to an array to a mongodb database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, authentication

I have a question regarding a server based website I built using node.js and express.
(I'm new to node.js and mongodb)

I added a login and sign in page to my website but right now it is only pushing the data given from the inputs of my sign in page to an array called users. Therefor after signing in the entered data is only saved locally for the current session of my server.
Now I want to get it to save the entered data to a mongodb database, so users are able to login any time with their data they used in a previous server session.
I have found many tutorials on youtube but they're all using different code for their login and sign in functions which is kind of confusing to me. I dont know if its possible but I would like to keep the code I used so I dont have to use new one.

My question is:
What do I need to add/change to my code to be able to save the data to a mongodb database instead of pushing it to an array like I did. And do my validation functions also work for validating the data from a database or do I need to change this as well.

This is my server.js code:

```
//imports
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const users = [];
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const passport = require("passport");
const initializePassport = require("./passport-config");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const session = require("express-session");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");


initializePassport(
    passport,
    name => users.find(user => user.name === name),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
    )

//app.use
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.set("view-engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride("_method"))


// Routes
app.get("/", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + "/public/index.ejs");
});

app.get("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + "/public/login.ejs");
});

app.get("/register", checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + "/public/register.ejs");
});

app.get("/generator", (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + "/public/index.ejs");
});

app.get("/manager", (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + "/public/man.ejs");
});


// register post function
app.post("/register", checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        users.push({
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        res.redirect("/login")
    } catch {
        res.redirect("/register")
    } 
    console.log(users)
});


//login post function
app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate("local",{
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}));


//logout function
app.delete("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logOut(req.user, err => {
        if (err) return next(err)
        res.redirect("/")
    })
})


//check for authentication functions
function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect("/")
    }
    next()
}

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect("/login")
}


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening port 3000"));
```

And this is the passport-config.js code:

```
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");



function initialize(passport, getUserByName, getUserById) {
    const authenticateUsers = async (name, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByName(name)
        if (user == null) {
            return done(null, false, {message: "No user found with that name"})
        } 
        try {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: "Password incorrect"})
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return done(e)
        }
    }

    passport.use(new localStrategy({usernameField: "name"}, authenticateUsers))
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done(null, getUserById(id))
    })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

Please dont blame me if my code is bad but as I mentioned Im new to the game and Im still trying to improve :)